# Write to a CSV file on two columns

Tags: php, file, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file. I have done this. I have put the below in a loop with the first and last lines outside of the loop.

```
$FileHandle = fopen('tech.csv', 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$stringa = $item." , ".$item2."\r\n";
fwrite($FileHandle, $stringa);
fclose($FileHandle);
```

However, it comes out like this in the CSV file:

```
a
b

c
d
```

Rather than the way I want it:

```
a b
c d
```

Basically, two columns rather than one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do $item and $item2 come from - because it looks like they already have a carriage return.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you read those values from a file/stream using [fgets()](http://docs.php.net/fgets)? Then the trailing linebreak is part of the string. Use [trim()](http://docs.php.net/trim) to remove the linebreak.

You might also be interested in the function [fputcsv()](http://docs.php.net/fputcsv).

Comment: Fantastic, trim did the job. The string is from a web page and I can imagine it having a trailing line break. Thanks VolKerK. :)

Answer (score 3):

I really hope you don't open and close the file in every iteration as that puts a real strain on the filesystem. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
$csv = array();
foreach($myData as $row) {
    $csv[] = trim($row['item1']).','.trim($row['item2']);
}
file_put_contents('tech.csv', implode("\r\n", $csv), FILE_APPEND);
```

Or, you could use the [fputcsv](http://docs.php.net/fputcsv) function:

```
$fp = fopen('tech.csv', 'a+');
foreach($myData as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, array(trim($row['item1']), trim($row['item2']));
}    
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: The code sample in the OP appends to an existing file (`a+`), whereas this code overwrites whatever is there.

Comment: @nickf, I suspect that's because he's doing the opening and closing in every iteration if I understood him correctly, but I changed my examples so that they're appending to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am not opening or closing in the loop! I said I put the first and second line outside the loop in my question. :)